# How to select counties, cities and regions from the custom drop-down menu？

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I select Taipei in the first menu and only display the area of Taipei in the second menu. How do I link the menus?
There is no v-model to monitor the custom menu, so I don’t know how to judge.
The methods part is the value that will be brought into the selection when you click.
Any help appreciated, thanks

```
<div class="form-control invoice-select">
    <div class="login-placeholder" @click="isAddShow=!isAddShow">{{ addPlaceholder }}
        <span class="arrow-icon" :class="{active:!isAddShow}"></span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="isAddShow" class="l-select-wrap">
        <li v-for="(item,i) in addSelectData" :key="i" @click="addSelectOption(item)"
            class="l-select-item">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- select area -->
<div class="form-control invoice-select">
    <div class="login-placeholder" @click="isAreaShow=!isAreaShow">{{ areaPlaceholder }}
        <span class="arrow-icon" :class="{active:!isAreaShow}"></span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="isAreaShow" class="l-select-wrap">
        <li v-for="(item,i) in addSelectData" :key="i" @click="areaSelectOption(item)"
            class="l-select-item">
            <span>{{item.areas}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


data:{
    addSelectData: [{
        name:"Taipei",
        areas: "A",
        areas: "B",
        areas: "C",
        areas: "D",
        areas: "E",
        areas: "F",
    },
    {
        name:"Taichung",
        areas: "A1",
        areas: "B1",
        areas: "C1",
        areas: "D1",
        areas: "E1",
        areas: "F1",
    },
    ],
    addPlaceholder: "Select county",
    areaPlaceholder: "Select area",
    isAddShow: false,
    isAreaShow: false,
}
methods:{
    //Click to replace the value
    addSelectOption(item) {
        this.addPlaceholder = item.name
        this.isAddShow = false
    },
    
    areaSelectOption(item) {
        this.areaPlaceholder = item.areas
        this.isAreaShow = false
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing it. I recommend you use computed properties provided by vuejs.

First change the duplicate keys you have object with same property. Your current object which will be read by JS as

```
addSelectData: [{
        name:"Taipei",
        areas: "F", // Object keys must be unique. this makes other area disappear
    },
    {
        name:"Taichung",
        areas: "F1",
    },
    ],
```

To avoid reading only latest key change it to array as shown in below format

```
addSelectData: [{
        name:"Taipei",
        areas: ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
    }
],
```

Now for the **isAreaShow** div we will create a new computed **selectedAreas** property.

```
    <ul v-show="isAreaShow" class="l-select-wrap">
        <li v-for="(item) in selectedAreas" :key="i" @click="areaSelectOption(item)"
            class="l-select-item">
            <span>{{item}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Then finally add your computed property

```
methods: { //your methods here },
computed: {
    selectedAreas: function() {
        if(this.isAreaShow){
            // Get the array where selected area lies
            let selectedItem = this.addSelectData.filter(item => item.name == this.addPlaceholder);
            // setting area to be object
            selectedItem = selectedItem.length ? selectedItem[0] : { areas: [] };
            // get values of object and remove selected area from it
            return selectedItem. areas;
        }
        return ["Select Area"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried to get the last value of Area only?

Comment: @ChiehYUWU Which one is it? Is it related to duplicate key? Please read the updated answer